# Do com.android.internal.R.attr and android.R.attr have the same set of values?

Tags: android

I need to use a built in value from Android resources. This value is stored `com.android.internal.R.attr.listViewStyle`. Being unable to get that from within my code, I tried to find the appropriate value I can use insted. Well, I've just found `android.R.attr.listViewStyle`.

Question 1: Are these values same?

Question 2: Where can I find the XML for `com.android.internal.R.attr.listViewStyle`? May be I have to create my own style instead that one. In order to find it out I should look at that file.

Sorry if these questions are silly. I'm new to Android development yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`com.android.internal` classes are internal to android, they are only accessible within frameworks.

I think `com.android.internal.R.attr.listViewStyle` and `android.R.attr.listViewStyle` are same.

If you want to create your own style you can check [here](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/themes.xml#428) . This contains two `listViewStyle`. They are used based on the device default theme(Light or dark).

If you want to use this style, then i think you dont need to specify anything in your code, this is default theme, so it is picked automatically, if no attributes are specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can add  listViewStyle in values/attr.xml with this code :

`<attr name="listViewStyle" format="reference" />`

Change `com.android.internal.R.attr.listViewStyle` in your code to  `R.attr.listViewStyle`

I find it in [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml)

Example for attr.xml

`< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

`< resources>`

`< attr name="listViewStyle" format="reference" />`

`</resources>`