# How to get Android's native progress bar indeterminate drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I was wondering if it was possible to retrieve Android's native `ProgressBar`'s **indeterminate drawable**, so that it can used on another view.

Looking at `ProgressBar`'s source code:

1. the default attributes are located at `com.android.internal.R.attr.progressBarStyle`, which I believe is the same as `android.R.attr.progressBarStyle` (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13438786/3535408)).
2. the resource id for the drawable I am looking for is `R.styleable.ProgressBar_indeterminateDrawable`

However, I have no luck accessing that styleable attribute itself.

Any idea on how to achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do in my app.  IIRC, this code was provided by Jake Wharton on the retrofit site for getting a progress bar while files are downloading.

```
fun getProgressBarIndeterminate(): Drawable? {
    val attrs = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.indeterminateDrawable)
    val attrsIndeterminateDrawableIndex = 0
    val a = App.getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar, attrs)
    return try {
        a.getDrawable(attrsIndeterminateDrawableIndex)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return null
    }finally {
        a.recycle()
    }
}
```